# float round-off in c++

Tags: c++

```
int a,b;
a = 2147483647;
b = 1000;
printf("%.2f",(float)a/(float)b);
```

This should print 2147483.65 but instead it prints out 2147483.75 please help

Comment: A float is only 32 bits, same as your `int`, but it has to support floating point values, by definition. The bits to do that have to come from somewhere. They can't exist in hyperspace, and take up no room in the real world, some of those 32 bits have to be reserved for such purpose. As such, a float does not have enough bits to represent 2147483647.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik means, **with your compiler** it's evident that...

Comment: `float` doesn't have that much precision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast a and b to `double` instead of `float`.

**Reason**:

The value of a in your program is 2147483647 which is the highest value that can be stored by a 4 byte long (32 bit) data type such as `int`. However `float` even though being a 32 bit data type truncates it because it has to account for fractional digits too. If you use `double` instead, it is 8 bytes long and hence can easily accommodate 2147483647 or 2147483.65.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have run out of memory space for storing the floating point value. I'll explain the issue by taking a broader perspective of the problem.

`2147483647` is the largest number that can be stored in an 32-bit signed int variable. If we see it in binary format, it is: 1111111111111111111111111111111. Now, even though a signed float is also 4 bytes (32-bit signed), a floating point variable also has to store values that are less than 1 and greater than 0. Therefore, you face a problem in the following line:

```
printf("%.2f",(float)a/(float)b);
```

Because when you cast a to a float, you inadvertently do `(float)(2147483647)`. Now since this number alone takes 31 bits (the 32nd bit is for the sign of the value; here it is zero, since the number is positive), and a float allocates some space for the fractional part of the value, you have less than 31 bits for the same value. This causes float overflow, and leads to the problem you are having.

So, to fix this, you should cast `a` to double. It is unrequired to cast `b`as a double since it fits within a float. Also, casting one variable in a mathematical operation is enough to have the compiler treat the result as the type which was casted to one of the variables.

So simply by doing:

```
printf("%.2f",(double)a/b);
```

You cast the end result to a type **double**, and it gives you the desired result **2147483.65**.

By the way, just as an aside, a double has 8 bytes of memory, twice of float's size. Therefore, it is more practical to use double in operations where precision is necessary.

Answer (score -2):

replace `float` with `double`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    long a,b;
    a = 2147483647;
    b = 1000;
    printf("%.2f",(double)a/(double)b);  // No need to cast both a/(double)b is enough
    return 0;
}
```

**o/p** : 2147483.65   [Check here](http://ideone.com/VITPdo)

This is because of float data type has to deal fractional part as well.